# What's the role of "atque" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, conjunction

This sentence comes from chapter XXII of *Lingua latina per se illustrata: Colloquia Personarum* (emphasis mine in the word I find difficult to understand):

> Putāsne mē tantum **atque** tam pulchrum ānulum aureum octō sēstertiīs vendere.

I understand its meaning, but I have some doubts about its construction. The first one is that, because of the presence of *-ne*, I believe it's a question. So, shouldn't it be an interrogation mark at the end?

The second one is about the role of the conjunction *atque*. I think that the sentence makes sense without this *atque*:

> Putāsne mē tantum tam pulchrum ānulum aureum octō sēstertiīs vendere?

So, what's the role of "atque" in the above cited sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the sentence should end with a question mark. Maybe Ørberg is playing a little loose with punctuation.

The role of *atque* does not seem particularly mysterious to me: *tantus **atque** tam pulcher anulus aureus* = such a big **and** pretty golden ring. In particular, two adjectives modifying the same noun have to be joined with a conjunction in Latin *if* they are on the same footing, i.e., not if one of them forms a closer bond with the noun than the other. This is shown here with *aureus*; "golden" as an attribute of "ring" is not on the same footing as "big" and "pretty," a golden ring is a type of ring, which can be big or small, pretty or plain, etc. -- at least that's how the Romans saw it.

Comment: I see... I thought that the meaning of "tantum" was "only" and qualified "octō sēstertiīs".

Comment: @Charo That seems to be the key to the confusion, then. Here *tantum* is masculine singular accusative of an adjective.

Comment: @Charo **Tantum** for *only* usually goes right behind the phrase expressing the limit (here **octo sestertiis**), or at least close to it, if in a non-poetic context.